# Kivy Labels are all acting together when one of them is touched

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am a beginner trying to make a Sudoku game with kivy. I created my own Buttons class which inherits from Kivy's Button class so I can define properties that all labels have in common, but I am running into an issue where if I press one of the labels, they all act together.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class SudokuLabel(Label):
    # Define colors
    bg_color = (250 / 255, 250 / 255, 250 / 255)
    font_color = (200 / 255, 200 / 255, 200 / 255)
    touch_bg_color = (58 / 255, 110 / 255, 223 / 255, 0.9)
    touch_font_color = (250 / 255, 250 / 255, 250 / 255)
    value = ""

    def __init__(self, value, **kwargs):
    super(SudokuLabel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.value = value
    self.color = self.font_color
    self.font_size = 32
    self.size_hint = 1/10, 1/18  # Grid fills 90% of screen horizontally, and 50% vertically
    
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    self.color = self.touch_font_color

def on_touch_up(self, touch):
    self.color = self.font_color

def __repr__(self):
    return str(self.value)
```

I suspected that the problem is with the way I am inheriting from the Label class, so I made another class to inherit from "SudokuLabel" where I define the "one_touch_down" method but that did not work. Any help is appreciated.

Also, I am not using a .kv file because I am creating the Sudoku sheet labels in a for loop, and I don't know if I can do that with the kv language. So please provide a python response if you have one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check collision.

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
        self.color = self.touch_font_color
        return True
```